# Generating permutations of values for each slot

Tags: scala, permutation, for-comprehension

OK, I must be struggling with something stupid here (new to Scala), in which case apologies if it is something trivial.

I have a class `Action` which takes a name (irrelevant for the problem) and a list parameters.

Each parameter has a set of possible values, and I want to generate the full list of possible arguments for the parameters of the `Action`. I have been trying to use a `for-comprehension` but rather than filling in all arguments, I am getting combinations with just one value replaced.

My code looks something like this (I simplified it just to illustrate the problem):

```
case class ParamType(name: String)
{
  def matchesType(that: ParamType): Boolean = 
      this.name == that.name
}

sealed abstract class Param (paramType : ParamType)

case class VarParam(parameter : String, paramType : ParamType) extends Param (paramType)

case class ValueArg(name : String, paramType : ParamType) extends Param(paramType)


case class Action(name: String, params: List[Param])
{
   def possibleActions(possibleValues : Set[ValueArg]) : Set[Action] = 
     for {
   parameter <- params.collect({case pt: VarParam => pt})
   argument <- possibleValues
   if (argument.matchesType(parameter))
   } yield replaceParam(parameter, argument)

   def replaceParam(parameter: VarParam, argument: ValueArg) : Action =
   {
     val i = parameters.indexOf(parameter)
     if (i >= 0)
       Action(name, parameters.updated(i, argument)
   }      
}




   object tester {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val possibleValues = Set[ValueArg](new ValueArg("a1", new ParamType("Atype")), 
                                       new ValueArg("a2", new ParamType("Atype")),
                                       new ValueArg("a3", new ParamType("Atype")),
                                       new ValueArg("b1", new ParamType("Btype")),
                                       new ValueArg("b2", new ParamType("Btype")),
                                       new ValueArg("b3", new ParamType("Btype")),
                                       new ValueArg("c1", new ParamType("Ctype")),
                                       new ValueArg("c2", new ParamType("Ctype")),
                                       new ValueArg("c3", new ParamType("Ctype")))

    val action1 = new Action("action1", List[Param](new VarParam("A", new ParamType("Atype")), new VarParam("B", new ParamType("Btype")), new VarParam("C", new ParamType("Ctype"))))

    val possibleActions = action1.possibleActions(possibleValues)

    println(possibleActions)

    }
   }
```

The function `replaceParam` just returns an action with the parameter replaced by the argument.

So if I have action1 with parameters A, B, C, each of which can take {a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3} and {c1, c2, c3} (assume they are of the same type), I am ending up with:

action1(a1, B, C) , action1(A, b1, C), action1(A, B, c1), action1(a2, B, C) etc.

But what I want is:

action1(a1, b1, c1), action1(a1, b1, c2), action1(a2, b1, c1) etc.

What is the most elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: do you want the cartesian product?

Comment: yeah sort of, if you look at it that way

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand what you are asking. Could you provide an example that compiles? With definitions for the `Param` class and example input.

Comment: @david Param is nothing special. It just has a name and a type. Then I have the domain of that parameter (i.e. the possible values), which I am filtering from the whole set of possibleValues using the matches type. I just want to generate all the combinations of different values I can provide to the `Action`. Let me add more stuff to have it compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a simple recursive solution to your problem. However, note that passing the possible values as a `Set` might turn out to be problematic because this way there is no order on the possible values and hence all (and not only one in particular) corresponding parameters will iterate over all values with suitable parameter types. Now this should do what you asked:

```
case class ParamType(name: String) {
  def matchesType(that: ParamType): Boolean =
    this.name == that.name
}

sealed abstract class Param(val paramType: ParamType)
case class VarParam(parameter: String, override val paramType: ParamType) extends Param(paramType)
case class ValueArg(name: String, override val paramType: ParamType) extends Param(paramType)

case class Action(name: String, params: List[Param]) {
  lazy val varParams: List[Param] =
    params collect {
      case pt: VarParam => pt
    }

  def possibleActions(possibleValues: Set[ValueArg]): Set[Action] = {
    val pvs  = possibleValues groupBy (_.paramType)
    def aux(acc: List[Param], rem: List[Param]): Set[Action] = rem match {
      case Nil => Set(Action(name, acc.reverse))
      case x :: xs => for {
        pv <- pvs(x.paramType) if pvs.contains(x.paramType)
        rest <- aux(pv :: acc, xs)
      } yield rest
    }
    aux(Nil, varParams)
  }
}

val possibleValues = Set(
  ValueArg("a1", ParamType("Atype")),
  ValueArg("a2", ParamType("Atype")),
  ValueArg("a3", ParamType("Atype")),
  ValueArg("b1", ParamType("Btype")),
  ValueArg("b2", ParamType("Btype")),
  ValueArg("b3", ParamType("Btype")),
  ValueArg("c1", ParamType("Ctype")),
  ValueArg("c2", ParamType("Ctype")),
  ValueArg("c3", ParamType("Ctype")))

val action1 = Action("action1",
  List(VarParam("A", ParamType("Atype")),
    VarParam("B", ParamType("Btype")),
    VarParam("C", ParamType("Ctype"))))

val possibleActions = action1.possibleActions(possibleValues)
assert(possibleActions.size == 3 * 3 * 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure I understood your concern about the `Set`. If I have 2 paramaters `A1` and `A2` of type `Atype` I do want the same value to be considered twice, so combinations `(a1, a1)`, `(a1,a2)`, `(a1, a3)`, `(a2, a1)`, `(a2, a2)`, `(a2, a3)`, `(a3,a1)`, `(a3,a2)`, `(a3,a3)`. Is this what you're referring to? In that case yes that is what I want to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: If that is what you want, then everything's just fine. I just felt the urge to point out that this might cause akward behavior if you were expecting otherwise :)

Comment: Oh ok Thanks. I guess one might think that I wouldn't want duplicate parameters to be considered right? trying your solution out.

Comment: Small question, you did the `lazy val varParams` outside to avoid having to compute it twice if the function `possibleActions` is called again? or for some other reason?

Comment: You're right. Didn't want to compute it twice and also only if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I also moved the `groupBy` out in the same way because its the same for all actions.